# Setting attribute of Django model instance in clean() when model has generic foreign key fails

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Here is a toy example to illustrate the problem:

```
# models.py
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class MyRelatedModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models.IntegerField()
    some_models = generic.GenericRelation('MyModel')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
    more_data = models.FloatField(editable=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

    def clean(self):
        super(MyModel, self).clean()
        self.more_data = 5.5

    def save(self, *args, **options):
        print self.more_data    # prints 'None'
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **options)
```

The following goes in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from test_model_save.models import MyModel, MyRelatedModel

class MyModelInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = MyModel

class MyRelatedModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MyModelInline]

admin.site.register(MyModel)
admin.site.register(MyRelatedModel, MyRelatedModelAdmin)
```

When I try to create an object in the Django admin, I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/test_model_save/myrelatedmodel/add/
test_model_save_mymodel.more_data may not be NULL
```

Before adding the generic foreign key to MyModel, the line `self.more_data = 5.5` in `clean()` successfully set the attribute value. In the example above, however, the attribute value is not persisted until `save()`. I am at a loss what might be causing this behavior. Am I doing something wrong?

(Tested using Django 1.4 with Sqlite backend)

**Edit:** The problem seems to be related to using the inlined interface in the admin. Creating objects of the two models separately works fine. Trying to create both types of objects on the same admin page (using the tabular inline interface) results in the IntegrityError above.

**Edit2:** If I change the generic foreign key in MyModel to a plain `models.ForeignKey(MyRelatedModel)`, the code works fine. So the problem is related to using a generic foreign key. At this stage this looks like a bug in Django.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `null=True` to the more_data field?  I suspect that the admin saves the parent model first and therefore validates the entire form before hitting your clean() method.

Good luck!

Comment: Adding `null=True` to `more_data` solves the IntegrityError, but the value saved in the database is NULL, rather than 5.5 as I would expect.